# Hiding element with reflow in JavaScript and how is it different from CSS hidden property?

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons, one passes **true** argument, another does not. Both buttons disappear when I press on them. But what exactly is going on behind the scenes for each button?

If this code looks familiar to you, it's from [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide 6th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996). Great book!

One more thing. In **C++** and **Java** omitting an argument would result in a compile-error. 
In **C#** you could change the second argument to be optional and it would work. In **JavaScript** I didn't have to do that. Are all arguments in JavaScript optional?

**JavaScript:**

```
function hide(e, reflow) {
    if (reflow) {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        e.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="hide(this,true); debug('hide button 1');">Hide1</button>
<button onclick="hide(this); debug('hide button 2');">Hide2</button>
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Behind the scenes: when you click button 1 - it disapears because of e.style.display = "none"; and when you click Button 2 - it disapears because of e.style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: @Dmitriy I am new to JavaScript and CSS. My question was what is the difference between the two statements. lord_t made it clear as to what happens when you do display = "none" and visibility = "hidden".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all arguments in JavaScript are optional.

With `display:none` is something similar to `width:0; height:0`, and if you set the `visibility` to `hidden` button stay on it's place, but it is invisible.

Comment: I've made my 2nd button 500px wide to see the difference and it's clear to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeap!

In Javascript you have all arguments optional. Actually you don´t need to name your arguments. There is a implicit var called "arguments" where you can find an array of your arguments. You can ever access your arguments through this var.

Take a look at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: And about the main question:
- visibility: you can hide your element and preserve the space where it was, leaving a empty gap in the layout;
- display: you can control how your control will appears on the page, as a block, as an inline element, or even so, hiding it;